# Sending emails using PHP

Tags: php, email, smtp, xampp, contacts

I am designing a contact form on a website and despite all the tutorials that I followed online to get it to work, it just isn't working.

I am currently using XAMPP for Windows and I know that I need to change my php.ini and sendmail but no matter how much I change my SMTP settings, I just cannot get the contact form to work.

Could someone please give me an up-to-date explanation of how this whole procedure works?

I am planning to put the website online eventually. When this comes, I suppose the php.ini and sendmail file from XAMPP won't matter anymore right?  So how does it work on a web server?

Thanks

Comment: Code and settings? If your host provider has SMTP you won't have problems

Comment: Code is as simple as this:
mail('...@example.com', 'Hello', 'This is a test email', 'From:...@example.com').  
I used this just to test whether the emails are being sent.  It's not working, so I'm guessing the problem is in the configuration.  My company has a mail server already set up and i know that our smtp port is 25 but it doesn't seem to work when I insert these settings in php.ini

Comment: You need to set up headers

Answer (score 0):

Your php.ini wont work on webserver.

On webserver most time, the emails are handled by their smtp relays. So do not worry about emails in webserver. For testing you just upload your email script on webserver at any address, and test it it works.

Here I am providing you code which should work on your webserver.

```
    $To = "email address of person whom you want to send email";
    $From = "your email address";
    $Subject = "subject of email";
    $Email = "your message";

    $Headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $Headers .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $Headers .= "From: " . $From . "\r\n";

    $mail = mail($To, $Subject, $Email, $Headers);

    if ($mail) {

        echo "email sent";

    } else {

        echo "email failed";

    }
```

Comment: I'm not too worried about emails in webserver. I guess testing it locally is a real pain though.  My code is similar to yours so the problem should be in my php.ini settings

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to set a valid smtp in your php.ini because sendmail is not used on Windows.
Use your ISP's smtp.

Comment: Tutorials I watched were on Windows and almost all of them made changes to sendmail. I have a valid smtp and inserted it in my php.ini but still didn't work. Do I only have to change SMTP and port in php.ini for it to work? Or are there more changes to be made in php.ini?

Comment: On Windows, only smtp server is used. Sendmail is for unix based system only.

; Windows : 
SMTP = smtp.myisp.com

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an remote [SMTP server, such as Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page%20SMTP%20server), to test the email sending locally. This avoids the need to have an email server configured in the current environment.

After you get your code on the server, you should then change the configurations to use the webserver email server.

Comment: The post that you linked uses Pear Mail package.  is there any way to do it by modifying only my xampp settings?